# how to controll a netcat reverse shell with python

Tags: python, shell, sockets

so i was using https://weibell.github.io/reverse-shell-generator/ to generate reverse shells and test them on a simple linux machine, i wanted to be able to control the reverse shell with some simple python sockets, and i thought if i just send text it would do the job, but after some testing it didn't work. in the reverse shell generator, they use `nc -lvnp {port}` i tried to use code as shown to try and control the reverse shell that was connected to the python server:

```
import socket
import threading
import time

port = 2008
ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((ip, port))

def handle_client(client_socket):
    print(client_socket)
    print("Sending data")
    client_socket.send(b"echo hello > test.txt")
    data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    if data != b"":
        print(data)

def main():
    print(f"Server started on port: {port} on ip: {ip}")
    server.listen()
    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server.accept()
        print(f"Connection from {addr}")
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket,))
        thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

currently this is my main script, it send a command to the reverse shell to generate a file using echo, when i first test it and it didn't work, i thought i was supposed to listen to any new data coming from the reverse shell, but that also didn't work, and that's why there is this line over here

```
data = client_socket.recv(1024)
if data != b"":
    print(data)
```

if anybody has any explanation to why the reverse shell didn't run my commands, or any suggestion/solutions to try and fix it, or even some explanation to the diffrences between the neetcat revese shell command and my code it would be highly apreciated

Answer (score 0):

after some time and debugging, i manage to find out what was the problem, i was sending the text as raw bytes, the fix was for me to encode the string to a utf-8 format or an ascii format instead, but i still haven't been able to controll a reverse shell from the pure netcat payload from the website